No preview pictures, if uploading files via Chromium
I want to upload a picture via Chromium.
I don't see previews of the jpeg files:

How to enable previews?
(In nautilus I see previews)

Is Chromium installed as a snap?

@muru yes, Chromium is installed as a snap.
